# Sorting function not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a very simple sorting function that sorts objects by `index`:

```
panoramas.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.index > b.index) return 1
})
```

Input:

```
[
  { index: 0 },
  { index: 2 },
  { index: 1 }
]
```

Output:

```
[
  { index: 1 },
  { index: 2 },
  { index: 3 }
]
```

The function works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE (the array isn't being sorted at all.)

Is there something wrong with my function?

Comment: I *suppose* it does not sort because your function has no explicit return value in the case `a.index <= b.index`.

Comment: @MartinNyolt How should I change the code to reflect that?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24080786/1314743).

Comment: `panoramas.sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index)`

Comment: Do you mean IE changes the values of the object properties? I mean the example code definitely doesn't sort arrays in any browser. Notice also, that IE doesn't support ES6 arrow functions.

Answer (score 4):

> The sorting function should return -1, 0 or 1 for the ordering.

```
// Your function tests for 'a.index > b.index'
// but it's missing the other cases, returning false (or 0)

panoramas.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.index > b.index) return 1;
  if (a.index < b.index) return -1;
  return 0;
})
```

*from* [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison/24080786#24080786)

- `> 0` when `a` is considered larger than `b` and should be sorted after it
- `== 0` when `a` is considered equal to `b` and it doesn't matter which comes first
- `< 0` when `a` is considered smaller than `b` and should be sorted before it

*for numbers*, you can use a more concise approach:

```
panoramas.sort((a, b) => {
   return a.index - b.index; 
   // but make sure only numbers are passed (to avoid NaN)
})
```

---

*for **IE11**,* that as noted by @teemu **doesn't support arrow functions**, you'll have to use a function expression:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

---

```
panoramas.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.index - b.index; 
});
```

Comment: `return a.index  - b.index` is much more concise.

Comment: thnx @MartinNyolt. had the verbose solution because I think it will be easier to understand